# Handling websockets in python

Tags: python, django, websocket, chat

I am developing a messaging service that uses websockets. And I shall be using python/django as a server side language. There are options such as:

1. Tornado
2. django-websockets-redis
3. Crossbar.io
4. Flask-SocketIO

I am confused by what should I be using for the production environment where the number of active connections is large.

Comment: Don't use Django. You will end up doing everything manually, as it has no support for websockets at all.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets in tornado are relatively straightforward. [This example](https://github.com/hiroakis/tornado-websocket-example/blob/master/app.py) shows how you can integrate websockets with extremely basic management (`open` and `on_close` methods).

For upstream traffic (browser -> server) you can implement the WebSocketHandler methods:

```
def on_message(self, message):
    # call message callback

def data_received(self, chunk):
    # do something with chunked data
```

For downstream traffic, there's `WebSocketHandler.write_message`:

```
def broadcast_to_all_websockets(self, message):
    for ws in cl:
        if not ws.ws_connection.stream.socket:
            print "Web socket %s does not exist anymore!" % ws
            cl.remove(ws)
        else:
            ws.write_message(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Highly suggest using [autobahn|Python](http://autobahn.ws/python/).  Currently using it right now for a WebSocket project in Python and it's so easy to work with and has a lot of classes already built for you like a WebSocketServer.  Let's you choose your implementation too (choice between asyncio and Twisted.)